# Thunderbird doesn't work on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: thunderbird, 19.10

Just updated to Ubuntu 19.10 and now getting this message, even after re-installing Thunderbird.

[image]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Have you tried renaming your Thunderbird profile to check if the problem lies with something in your profile?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely Mozilla will reply to you soon, so suggest you move ahead with a diagnostic test.

Please make sure Files is set to show hidden and system files

In Files, go to **~/.thunderbird** (**.thunderbird** in your home directory)

Move the profile file (which ends in **.default**) from there to any other directory under ~/ you choose.

Then, run Thunderbird again, and it will create a new profile automagically. Fill in the questions it asks you, and then try to send a message.

If it works, well, your profile was corrupted; like Outlook, user profiles with a bazillion emails get big and complicated sometimes.

If it does not work, report back.